RATE and IRATE usage for a query to Prometheus
here is the query to the Prometheus HTTP API
var query = "query=\'ifHCInOctets{instance=~\"MYROUTER.xxx\"} and ifHCInOctets{ifName=~\"et-1/1/1\"}\'"
How can I use "rate" and "irate" ?
Thanks
I tried :
rate(ifHCInOctets{ifName=~\"et-1/1/1\"}[10m])\'"
The result is identical, with a very large number
